# Building libFLAC on OSX with i386 arch not x86_64

Tags: macos, gcc, architecture, autotools

I'm trying to build libFLAC to use in a project of mine, however when it comes to linking, GCC ignores the library because it says it was not built for the current architecture (i386). When I compile the program in 64-bit, it links the library properly which means the library was compiled for x86_64 architecture. Unfortunately, my program wont work in 64-bit, so I need to compile libFLAC as i386. I've tried using ./configure --build=i386 however it didn't seem to change anything.

So far, I've simply been doing this:
./configure --disable-asm-optimizations --build=i386
make
sudo make install

But it always seems to build for x86_64.

Does anyone know how I can force it to compile for a certain architecture?

Comment: Try `./configure CFLAGS='-arch i386'`. You might need other CFLAGS as well, but give it a try.

Comment: Thanks I tried CFLAGS='-arch i386' CPPFLAGS='-arch i386' and --build=i386 and it seemed to work. Care to post as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim from my comment:

Try `./configure CFLAGS='-arch i386'`. You might need other `CFLAGS` as well, but give it a try.